# Django get distinct results from queryset based on value

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, distinct

Here, I have my query result

```
<QuerySet [{'user__first_name': 'aakash', 'user__id': 1, 'games_played': 1}, {'user__first_name': 'prakash', 'user__id': 2, 'games_played': 2}, {'user__first_name': 'prakash', 'user__id': 2, 'games_played': 2}]>
```

and my query is,

```
Games.objects.filter(Match__player__id=1).values('user__first_name', 'user__id').annotate(games_played=Count(Case(When(Q(status=Games.COMPLETE), then='id'))))
```

So here I want user prakash or user__id=2 to come once.

Comment: Add `.order_by('user__first_name', 'user__id', 'accounts__id')` at the end.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `.order_by` at the end to force the queryset to "fold":

```
Games.objects.filter(
    Match__player__id=1
).values(
    'user__first_name', 'user__id', 'accounts__id'
).annotate(
    games_played=Count(Case(When(Q(status=Games.COMPLETE), then='id')))
).order_by('user__first_name', 'user__id', 'accounts__id')
```

Note however that here the `JOIN`s will act as a "multiplier": you will count the number of *ids* times the number of matches where the player has `id=1`.

You probably want add `distinct=True` to avoid that in the `Count(..)`:

```
Games.objects.filter(
    Match__player__id=1
).values(
    'user__first_name', 'user__id', 'accounts__id'
).annotate(
    games_played=Count(Case(When(Q(status=Games.COMPLETE), then='id')), distinct=True)
).order_by('user__first_name', 'user__id', 'accounts__id')
```